# What can cause connection refused on unix socket file

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, nginx, fastcgi

I have nginx server installed and I use spawn-fcgi to create a socket but for some reason the socket refuses the connection from nginx.

```
This is my config:
    location /sympa {
        gzip off;
        include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/sympa/wwsympa.socket;

        # If you changed wwsympa_url in sympa.conf, change this regex too!
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/sympa)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/cgi-bin/sympa/wwsympa.fcgi;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
```

Error:

```
2018/02/10 15:21:37 [error] 4405#4405: *5 connect() to unix:/var/run/sympa/wwsympa.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /sympa HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/sympa/wwsympa.socket:", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using IP sockets here. 'Connection refused' means nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP Where is my IP socket here. It says "unix:/var/run/sympa/wwsympa.socket".  Also this file does exist.The question is how do I fix this?

Comment: I'm having similar issue when trying to start podman on local socket file. it says connection refused. as it's not IP:port, so would like to find out what actually can stop this connection from happening and how to find it out.